# Using Regex for page names in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to filter Google analytics results by page, but my URLs are user dependent, so the pages

> mysite.com/123/this-page

and

> mysite.com/456/this-page

are the same. I want google to group them as `/this-page` but google analytics treats them as different pages. I know the regex I want to use (something like `"/.*$"`) but I can't figure out where in Google analytics I can use that to make a custom filter or change the page definition, or make a custom view.

Any ideas where I can use this regex to group visits to my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go in `Administration` > `Filters` > and click `Add filter`.
- Once in the panel `Add Filter to View`, go in the section `Filter Type`, choose the `Custom` one and select the `Search and Replace` option.
- Finaly, in the `Filter field` selector, choose `Request URI`. You can
  now replace `Search String` with `Replace String` using regular
  expressions.

**NB:** your regexp `/.*$` matches all of your pages.